# Create records in has_and_belongs_to_many models from .csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two spreadsheets of data saved in separate Google spreadsheets, Stores and Products.

Stores has columns for:

- Store name
- Store location
- Store ID

Products has columns for:

- Product name
- Product cost
- Product ID
- Store ID

In Rails, I have two models - **Store** and **Product** - connected with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. The models have attributes matching each of the columns in the spreadsheets.

I'm looking to create a rake task that takes the spreadsheets as CSV files and creates linked rows in the Stores and Products databases, but being a coding newbie I'm finding it difficult. Adding data to one table from a .csv seems easy enough, but how can I use the matching "Product ID" column to link the data in the two csv files?

Comment: I should also add that the list above looks like a one-to-many relationship rather than HABTM. However, I'll be adding associations later so that each Store has multiple Products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I would do something like the following:

1. Start by creating the stores first as they are independent.  As you create the store and save the object, add the store object to a hash of {storeid:}
2. Then read in the products.csv (I'm assuming that there will be more than one product per store?).
3. For each row in the product csv, create the product object and then set the association by looking up the store object from your hash with the id in the row you are reading, finally save your product object.

   ```
   class Store < ActiveRecord::Base  

   end


   class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  

     has_and_belongs_to_many :stores  

   end
   ```

For rails I would guess that there is a quick way to do this via one of the many tools (rake etc).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Has_and_belongs_to_many is depreciated in newest rails, might want to move to Has_many_through :Store_Products (link table with :product_id and :store_id)

Then create with a rake file as

Store_Products.create(:product_id => '1', :store_id => '1')

Might want to take a look at this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` has not been deprecated. According to the guide you link to: "The use of extra attributes on the join table in a has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated." But HABTM survives.